# L^p-spaces in R

Tags: lp-spaces

Let $\Omega = (0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R: x \to (x(\log(x))^2)^{-\frac{1}{p}}$

In the lecture, we had this statement: $f \in L^p (\Omega)$ but $f \not \in L^{p+ \epsilon} (\Omega)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Why does this hold true?

Comment: Are you sure that $\Omega=(0,1/2)$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just computation.
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega|f(x)|^p\,dx&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\,(\log x)^2}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_t^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\,(\log x)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\log 2}\\
&<\infty.
\end{align}
This shows $f\in L^p$. Now let $q=(p+\epsilon)/p>1$.
$$
\int_\Omega|f(x)|^{p+\epsilon}\,dx=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x^q\,(\log x)^{2q}}.
$$
Comparison with $1/x$ shows that the integral diverges.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Julián! It seems quite clear to me now. But I have one last question: What if $\Omega = B(0, \frac{1}{2})$ (the open 2-dim disc centered at the origin with the radius 0.5)? An unbound function in $H^1(\Omega)$ could be, for example, the same function using our q, or not?

Comment: A change to polar coordinates would lead to similar computations.